# setTimeout on object method - ES5 bind, or closure?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Let's say I'm doing some animations with the HTML5 Canvas.  If I'm looking to animate an object's method, which would be preferable, performance wise (assuming I don't care about IE8):

```
setTimeout(this.render.bind(this), 15);
```

or

```
var self = this;
setTimeout(function () { self.render() }, 15);
```

My particular case isn't intense enough to really make a difference visually; I'm just trying to find out the best practice.

I would think creating a new function with `bind` would have less overhead than creating a closure, but I wanted to ask the experts.

Comment: this smells like over optimisation to me, then again i dont know what your problem is, but i think its safe to say that 75% of the time this doesnt matter

Comment: They both create a closure, the only difference is what scope those functions are bound in...

Comment: @mkoryak - it's only over-optimization if you're doing more work.  Both are trivial to implement, and I was wondering which is (potentially) more performant.

Comment: If browser support isn't a consideration, then use `.bind()`. Its entire purpose is to eliminate the need for `var self = this` hacks.

Comment: @amnotiam - that makes a lot of sense.  Plus, it just looks so cool :-D

Comment: I don't think there is any difference here, but note that `.bind` will pass arguments along whereas the closure does not. (Though this doesn't play any role with `setTimeout`.)

Comment: @Rob - are you sure?  `this` inside of the setTimeout callback will be undef/window, but render is being called as a method of `self`, so, once render hits, `this` will be what it should be.  But you knew that.  You're just saying there's a slight, pedantic difference between the actual functions you're passing to setTimeout, right?

Comment: @32bitkid: Are you saying that a native `.bind()` uses a closure in a manner similar to the second example?

Comment: @amnotiam the [mdn documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) implies they are at least *very* similar in implementation, *at most* you are saving one lexical scope look up, and at best they are equivalent.

Comment: @AdamRackis Sorry for the confusion, I looked at the wrong direction. As for the second example, I would save one local variable, by moving `this` to an argument of `setTimeout` (as you can see in my deleted answer).

Comment: @32bitkid: Yeah, that's what I was wondering. I thought I remembered from the spec that they were simple internal references from object to  object, with the new one setting and using the internals of the original. But I think you're right that regarding performance, it won't make a worthwhile difference.

Comment: @Rob - cool, but isn't that extra parameter to setTimeout non-standard?  Does it enjoy wide support?

Comment: @AdamRackis It's supported in all (modern) browsers, AFAIK. According to [this spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html), the extra arguments can be passed. In ancient browsers, the first argument had to be a string. With this string signature, no additional arguments were accepted.

Comment: @AdamRackis: If you like `.bind()`, just wait until they work in [this new function syntax proposal](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:shorter_function_syntax). It's not official yet, but we can hope! Specifically see the *Lexical this* section.

Comment: @amnotiam - ohhhh - so beautiful.  C# already has inline methods, lets hope JS catches up!

Comment: @AdamRackis you might as well just use [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/), because its pretty much all syntactical sugar.

Comment: @32bitkid - coffeescript seems very cool, but I just have a (possibly irrational) aversion to writing code in an intermediate language just to compile it to a language I already know.  Plus there are a lot less people who know CS compared to JS.

Comment: @RobW: *"It's supported in all (modern) browsers"* Not IE9 (and so presumably not earlier). And in Firefox, the timer function receives an additional argument after all of the others (the actual length of the timeout), which can *really* confuse people. Test: http://jsbin.com/uremum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript performance questions are tricky, because the various engines out there have very different performance characteristics. What's fast on one engine is slow on another.

Your closure should be very fast indeed; after all, all functions are closures and your `self` variable is defined in the immediately-containing context (so there isn't a lot of looking through the scope chain for it).

But in theory, an engine that supports ES5 features natively could optimize how `bind` works, making it even faster (no need for even just the one scope chain lookup).

Does it matter? No. I'd use what makes sense to you. Note that IE8 isn't the only browser out there that doesn't yet have ES5 features natively (although you can always use one of the es5 shims; unlike some ES5 features, `bind` can be perfectly emulated by shims in ES3 code — although to do it they have to use `call`/`apply`, which may be slower than a closure on some engines).